# How do I restore from a previous commit on Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, git, github, commit, git-commit

Let's say I have 5 local commits:

- commit 1
- commit 2
- commit 3
- commit 4
- commit 5

At this point when I'm working, I'd like to go back to commit 2.

How would I do so?

This was so easy using snapshots in previous versions of Xcode.

"Discard changes" only goes back to commit 5, right?

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 9:

1. Choose Source Control navigator.
2. Select (branch) committed project.
3. Click "Editor->Checkout ...", or click "Editor->Branch->Checkout ..."

This works for me, it restores the entire project at once.

Answer (score 3):

You need to

> git checkout COMMIT_2_ID

More info in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/1163930

Answer (score 1):

You can use the version editor in XCODE to do revert each of your files to the previous version. Go to View > Version Editor > Show Version Editor. There is a timeline icon at the bottom of the split view. You can revert to previous commits.